# A query regarding continuous functions in general topology

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

A continuous function $f$ between two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ is generally defined as follows $f:X\to Y$ is such that for every open subset $V$ of $Y,$ the set $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open subset of $X.$

In this definition only I have a confusion/doubt: it is not mentioned anywhere that $f$ is bijective. So how can we take the inverse of $f$ and define the continuity of $f$ ? Moreover, there is *homeomorphism* in which it is necessary for $f$ to be bijective and hence speaking of $f^{-1}$, in this regard, makes sense.

Also, *measurable functions* in measure theory are defined in a similar fashion to that of continuous functions in topology. Here also I am confused about the same thing! Please give some insights. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $f^{-1}(V)$ doesn't mean inverse function evaluated at $V$, but rather the pre-image of $V$ under $f$, that is $$f^{-1}(V) = \{x\in X \mid f(x)\in V\}.$$  You are correct in saying that $f$ need not be bijective in these definitions, but that isn't necessary for what the notation means.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of thinking of $f^{-1}(V)$ as it its inverse think about it as its **preimage**, that is:

$$
f^{-1}(V) :=\{x \in X : f(x) \in V \}
$$
If $f$ is a bijection there is a chance for it to be a homeomorphism.

In the case of measurable functions, it is very similar: A function is measurable if given a measurable set in the codomain then its **preimage** is measurable.